# Como hago en lenguaje C para cambiar un pixel de color?

Tags: c, windows

Se que hoy en día hay formas más fáciles de dibujar en pantalla, pero quiero por un minuto no abstraerme tanto y entender como sería la forma más básica de dibujar en pantalla teniendo en cuenta que estoy trabajando en C.

Desde ya les agradezco la paciencia.
Saludos.

Comment: Es siempre muy importante que digas que probaste, intentaste o investigaste para esto. Mira [ask]

Comment: muchas gracias por el consejo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estoy varia mucho dependiendo del sistema operativo, por tu etiqueta es claro que preguntas para windows.

Primero que todo cambias un pixel en un contexto, sea la consola o un widget etc, así funciona openGL por ejemplo, que es una biblioteca de renderizado. Se hizo una pregunta muy similar y la respuesta que se dio sirve como respuesta para tu pregunta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12378642/c-pixels-in-console-window

Utiliza [SetPinxel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa453646.aspx) del encabezado `windows.h` te animo a que le des un vistazo.

---

**EDITADO 1**

Agrego una pequeña explicación del código de ejemplo mostrado en el link y agrego una pequeña modificación porque el código dibuja la función coseno y tu solo necesitas un píxel.

```
#include<windows.h>   

int main() 
{
    //Obtiene el identificador de la consola
    HWND myconsole = GetConsoleWindow();
    //Obtiene el identificador del dispositivo del contexto
    //En este caso es la consola
    HDC mydc = GetDC(myconsole);

    //Elige el color
    COLORREF COLOR= RGB(255,255,255); 

    //Son las coordenadas del pixel a modificar
    int crdX = 5, crdY = 10;


    //Dibuja pixel
    SetPixel(mydc,crdX, crdY, COLOR);

    ReleaseDC(myconsole, mydc);
    return 0;
}
```

Como te había mencionado, el dibuja es en un contexto, el contexto puede ser cualquiera que sea compatible, en este caso es la consola, y es pasado a SetPixel, esta tiene como prototipo la siguiente forma:

Es citado tal cual esta en la documentación de Microsoft, solo fue traducido por mi.

> Esta función establece el píxel en las coordenadas especificadas para el color especificado.
>
> COLORREF **SetPixel**(
>    HDC hdc, 
>    int X, 
>    int Y, 
>    COLORREF crColor
>   );
>
> **Parametros**
>
> *hdc*
>      [in] Manejador del contexto del dispositivo.
>
> *X*
>      [in] Especifica la coordenada X, en unidades lógicas, del punto a establecer
>
> *Y*
>      [in] Especifica la coordenada Y, en unidades lógicas, del punto a establecer
>
> *crColor*
>      [in] Especifica el color que se utilizara para pintar el punto.
>
> **Valores de Retorno**
>
> 1. El valor RGB que la función establece al píxel indica éxito.
> 2. Este valor puede diferir con el color especificado por crColor; esto
>      sucede cuando no se puede encontrar una coincidencia para el color
>      especificado.
> 3. –1 indica falla.
>
> Para conseguir información extendida del error, llame a [GetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms885627.aspx).
>
> **Observaciones**
>
> La función falla si las coordenadas de píxel se encuentran fuera de la región de recorte actual.
>
> No todos los dispositivos con compatibles con SetPixel. Para obtener más información, consulte [GetDeviceCaps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms929230.aspx)

Comment: Wow muchisimas gracias. Disculpas por ser noob en stackoverflow